# Finite Groups: $a \in G \implies a \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup. Let $a$ be an element
of G and suppose that $\gcd(|a|,[G : H]) = 1$. Show that $a$ is in $H$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the factor group $G/H$. Since $a\in G$, $aH$ is an element of $G/H$.

Recalling and applying Lagrange's Theorem, we have that $|aH|$ must divide $|G/H|$.

Now, that $\gcd(a, |G:H|)=1$ implies what about the order of $aH$ in $G/H$?

Comment: @Hunter, did you get the last step?

Comment: Does this imply that aH=e?

Comment: @Hunter, exactly. $aH=H$, which is the identity element of $G/H$.

Comment: sorry I just re-read the question but yes

Comment: I think you mean $H$, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt on this question, I believe it's correct. Are there some suggestions that the community could send my way?

The quotient $G/H$ is a group as $H$ is normal in $G$. $G$ and $H$ are finite groups so $[G:H]=|G/H$|. Let $[G:H]=m$ and say $|a|=n$. For $aH\in G/H$,  $\langle aH \rangle \leq G/H$. By definition the order of $a$ is the least integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$. Now $(aH)^n = a^nH = eH
= H$, thus $|\langle aH\rangle|=n$. Using Lagrange's Theorem $[G:H]/|\langle aH\rangle| = m/n$, but $gcd(n,m)=1$. This forces $|a|=1$ hence $a=e$ and $a\in H$. Moreover, $aH$ is the identity element in $G/H$.

Comment: Looks good to me.